# What's the Name of this Natural Disaster Movie? It's possibly a Sci-Fi action Film too

Tags: story-identification, movie

The Natural Disaster Action Movie I'm asking about is about a meteor that fell from space to earth. A man and either his daughter or wife stumble upon the meteor and inside they find a plant-like thing (similar to the one in the 2001 comedy movie, *Evolution*). The man pulls the giant meteor with his truck and takes it to their home. They discover that that plant-like thing grows roots and cures diseases, bruises, etc. It also gives warnings to them that something is going to destroy earth. At the end, the man and the woman survive along with the plant-like thing inside a cement mixer or cement truck. The truck looks like the one from the 2009 movie *2012: SuperNova*.

That's all I know because my uncle told me about this movie, but doesn't know the name of it. All I remember is that he said it's around the year 2000 to now, But it's not a comedy movie, it's like a suspenseful and action movie.

Comment: Do you know approximately what decade it's from? The plot sounds like a lot of 1950s schlock sci-fi-horror B-movies.

Comment: The Monolith Monsters and Invasion of the Body Snatchers sound close, but it's hard to pin down with any specific details.

Comment: It *does* sound like Evolution, now that you mention it.

Comment: My uncle said it's around 2000's to Now, its in that year region

Comment: Note that the duplicate target suggested seems to have been incorrectly closed as a duplicate of something else. It does appear to be the same one as this, based on previews in accepted answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your description matches the movie [*Terminus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminus_(2015_film)) (2015): extraterrestrial object with healing powers, worldwide apocalypse, shelter made from old machinery.

Trailer (2 minutes; contains brief profanity):

Here's the cement mixer:

[image: Terminus cement mixer]

---

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! we've been looking for that movie since October!!!!